# Trying to use proxy but still get original ip address

Tags: network, wifi, proxy

I bought a private proxy server which I'm successfully using in Telegram application.

Now I went to network preferences (I'm using wifi connection), selected SOCKS proxy and filled credentials. Internet connection works, however when I check my ip address on few sites I got my original ip.

Plus, I noticed, that first time I filled wrong user/password but didn't get any error.

So how can I actually check if my wifi connection uses socks proxy, and why I get original IP? Pretty sure proxy is alive (anyway if it's not I should get some kind of error?)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain this is an Apple related question but rather a general networking one.  This proxy server, is it on prem, hosted, or IaaS?

Comment: No idea :) I'm not sure if I can post here address where I bought it, it says just premium private proxy.

Comment: Is it a physical proxy (sitting on your network) or a proxy (also physical) sitting at a another company, or is it a service (cloud) you just pay for?

Comment: Cloud, I pay for it. For now I bought VPN and I'm fine with it, but just curios if I can set up socks5 proxy on my wifi...actually..  I hope I can post it here: http://www.bestproxyandvpn.com/